# Selecting the correct software licence suited to my needs?

Tags: open-source, licensing, codeplex

I have a few applications that I will be uploading to CodePlex in the very near future.

Anybody is free to look at the source code and use it in their own applications but all I ask is that I am recognised as the original developer of the code and that it cannot be used in any commercial application without my permission.

I have looked at [Jeff's overview of licences](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/pick-a-license-any-license.html) but i'm still a bit confused as to which licence is best suited for my requirements.

There may be a time where I wish the code to only be used with my permission only, is it possible to change the terms of the licence after the code has been published?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a project to codeplex it will let you choose a license. Infact you wont be able to publish without choosing a license for you project. Best thing would be to read through every license listed and choose the best.

I always choose the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to change the terms of
>   the licence after the code has been
>   published?

This is a subject of some debate, but the consensus seems to be that you cannot revoke a license. In other words, if you change or add licences, the users who obtained and  use your work under the original license are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a license barring commercial usage; even the super-strict GPL lets derivatives be sold.

Although it's not recommended for software, I might go with a Creative Commons license in this situation, specifically the [Attribution-Noncommercial](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) license ([here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/uk/)'s a license with U.K. as the jurisdiction).

This license will require people give credit to you, while giving them the freedom to use it for a noncommercial project. It also has a clause allowing people to ask for your permission to override the license (i.e. use commercially).

Comment: P.S. I found out that you can't use any license you want; I'm leaving my answer though, in case the OP decides to use a different project hosting site that lets you use any license of your choosing, like GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, I have decided to use the Ms-PL licence for the time being and if I decide to change my hosting site i'll be sure to take your points in consideration.